# Why does regex [!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|\[{\]};:\'<,.>/?~`]+ match digits?

Tags: python, regex

Can someone explain the following result?

Input to python 2.7.12 shell

```
re.match('[!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|\[{\]};:\'<,.>/?~`]+', '2222').group()
```

Output:

```
'2222'
```

I don't understand why digits match this expression.

Comment: CNR. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: Same thing on IDEOne.com as well: http://ideone.com/P4kBn1

Comment: Escape the hyphen.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense -- it's a question of characterset collation order whether `2` is between `)` and `_` in the locale where this code is running. @WiktorStribiżew, excellent catch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think you failed to reproduce it because one of the ``\``s didn't show up due to the bad formatting, not because of a locale issue.

Comment: From testing on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ylBxxQ/1): *`)-_` a single character in the range between `)` (ASCII 41) and `_` (ASCII 95) (case sensitive)*

Comment: @user2357112, ahh; that makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

```
re.match('[!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|\[{\]};:\'<,.>/?~`]+', '2222').group()
#                   ^^^
```

`)-_` inside the brackets is a character range, and `2` is in that range.